# Generate errorhandler for XMLAplicationContext

Tags: android, apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-builder

I'm a flex developer and have a small problem.
I use XMLApllicationContext to load an XML file.

I load my context and then add the config location to it.

In this files I take care of creating an URL to connect to.So I made an eventlistner for my XMLApplicationContext with Event.COMPLETE so I know when he's done and he can connect.

No I'm a little bit dummytesting and if the user has given a wrong host and port the URL will not exist. So there will never be an Event.COMPLETE action.

For that I would love to know how I can solve this.

Now I have this code:

```
    public function execute():*
    {
        m_context = new XMLApplicationContext("application-context.xml");
        m_context.addConfigLocation("application-context-services.xml");
        m_context.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
        m_context.addEventListener(......);//need to know what has to come between the brackets
        m_context.load(); 
        ServiceLocator.getInstance().context = m_context;
    }
```

I allready tried some things but haven't found a solution yet.

Thank you in advance.

Kind regards,

Thibault Heylen

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the [IOErrorEvent](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/)?

If that doesn't work for you, you could try creating a file reference and check if it exists ...

```
var f:File = new File("application-context.xml");

if (f.exists) { 
    //...
}
```

Im not quite sure, but if this is a local file you maybe have to add `"app:/path/to/file/"` in front of your url/file name

Comment: thank for the response...but that's not my problem. He finds the file but from there he has to get an url and connect to it. So I have an eventlisteren for Event.complete but I want to get an eventlisteren if he can't connect to the url

Comment: ok, but maybe I'm not only one missing what you want and you should explain a little further. is the `XMLApplicationContext` you are ussing is [this one](https://src.springframework.org/svn/se-springactionscript-as/trunk/spring-actionscript-core/src/main/actionscript/org/springextensions/actionscript/context/support/XMLApplicationContext.as) there is definitely an IOError dispatched and you should be able to add an eventListener to it.